# Default length of suggestion item in rich:autocomplete

Tags: jsf, autocomplete, richfaces

There is a default value for the length of the displayed suggestion from `rich:autocomplete` tag. I can't find which attribute controls this value.

`popupClass` and `inputClass` define the style of the input box and poup box respectively.

But it doesn't affect the length of the text displayed.

Does anyone know how I can change the length of text displayed ?

Comment: Do you want to set the minimum amount of characters that activates the suggestion method or the length of the component (style)?

Comment: Hi,
I am looking for the attribute to set the length of the suggestion string returned from the server.
popupClass sets style of the popup box, but it doesn't change the length of the string returned from the server.

Comment: No. The attribute `minchars` indicates the minimum amount of chars that the user has to enter to activate the suggestion popup, as the answer below explains. Here you have its javadoc: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/autocomplete.html

Comment: @jmrodrigg you just repeated what I said above. I was saying the same thing. I am looking for the attribute that manipulates the length of the string that is displayed as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `minChars` attribute for controlling the minimum number of characters to be entered for auto complete to start working.

```
<rich:autocomplete minChars="2"  />
```

And as far as max characters is considered, when a User starts entering a very long text and doesn't find what he is searching for in the suggestion box, you think User will still continue typing them?

Comment: Vikas,
minChars is used to set the minimum characters required trigger the autocomplete function.
I am looking for the attribute to set the length of the suggestion string returned from the server. Returned suggestion string is getting chopped off at a fixed length.

Comment: Have you checked your suggestion method? Maybe it's getting the information (from your source - DB, file, ...) wrongly or it's not long enough to store the whole string... It's weird.

Comment: @Ravi As jmrodrigg rightly pointed out it has to do with your DB query. Please have a look at it again. And, I guess, this has not got to do with `popupClass` or `inputClass`. Its more related to your method which returns the suggestion string. Please check in the logs if you are getting the correct string. Please check the String which is holding that value.

Comment: @Vikas , I did check the DB Query and it is returning the full string.
In fact, once the suggestion is selected, it shows the full string.

Comment: ... you can trim the string returned from your DB, don't you? I thought your problem was that the DB wasn't returning the whole string... but it seems to be that you want to trim your result, isn't it?

Comment: @jmrodrigg DB is returning the whole string,but JSF is trimming it. I am trying to dind out how to stop that.

Comment: @Ravi Can you please paste your code.(Suggestion method and JSF code)